# React conditional rendering - executes code of alternate condition component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Content.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
const Content = () => {
    console.log('content called');
    return (<div>Content</div>);
};

export default Content;
```

**App.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import Content from './Content';

const App = () => {
const isUserAuthenticated = false;
return (
          <div>
            {
                isUserAuthenticated 
                ? <Content/>
                : <></>
            }
          </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Even though the condition is false, **Content** component gets loaded and console.log is executed.

Is it because I have imported the file ?
I do not see the HTML added to the DOM though.

Comment: check is Content used somewhere else

Comment: @sojin No, this is the only place, where Content is used

Answer (score -1):

**Can you try this on your `App.js` :-**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Content from './Content';

const App = () => {
const isUserAuthenticated = false;
return (
          <div>
            {isUserAuthenticated  && <Content/>}
          </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work

Comment: Then it's not a problem with your code. It's something else you did wrong by mistake or something. have tried to refresh your browser tab or restart your react server ?

Comment: rafi there was some issue with state. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I would also go ahead and say you are using it somewhere else, and you haven't noticed. Look through your code!

I put up this sandbox real quick to check it for myself, and the conditional rendering works as expected.
[Check if out](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-matsumoto-l6bdo?file=/src/App.js) if you'd like.